# JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0) Trying to Find Location Via User IP

Tags: python, json

```
import json
import geocoder
g = geocoder.freegeoip('')
g.json
```

Essentially this just grabs your lat/long coordinates using your ip when you run it.

When I try I am returned with this:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

JSONDecodeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-36-09a3ee1f4b06> in <module>()
----> 1 g = geocoder.freegeoip('')
      2 g.json

<8 frames>

/usr/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py in raw_decode(self, s, idx)
    353             obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
    354         except StopIteration as err:
--> 355             raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
    356         return obj, end

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

I have zero idea what this means or why I am having this problem.

The end goal of this snippet is to return a user's ip so it can be used later in the program.

Comment: I tried the same and got the same error. even installed the previous version but the same error.
I think you should open an issue for the same https://github.com/DenisCarriere/geocoder/issues/

Comment: I think it's an issue with freegeoip, using geocoder.ip('me') works perfectly fine and gets the exact same result. Perhaps I just found older code and geocoder updated it to .ip rather than .freegeoip.